# How to remove string between unbalanced brackets in Python3 without Regex?

Tags: python-3.x

Good day!

I have a string like  `esdfd((esdf)(esdf` i want to remove brackets and data if brackets don't close, should be like this --> `esdfd((esdf)`. Also, I can't use regex.

Thank you!

Comment: The example output is also unbalanced in your example, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you give more examples of input and output strings?

Comment: input -->  aaaa(bbbb)(ccccc       output --> aaaa(bbbb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def remove_unbalance(s):
    last_open = s.rfind("(")
    last_close = s.rfind(")")
    return s[:last_open] if last_open > last_close else s

print(remove_unbalance("aaaa(bbbb)(ccccc"))
# aaaa(bbbb)

print(remove_unbalance("esdfd((esdf)(esdf"))
# esdfd((esdf)

print(remove_unbalance("aaaa((bbbb)(ccccc) ddd"))
# aaaa((bbbb)(ccccc) ddd
```